# Why will input type radio not become selected in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
 <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in languages_sys">
  <input type="radio" ng-click="changeDefaultLanguage(key)" ng-value="{{key}}" ng-model="language">
   <span>{{value}}</span>
</li>
```

When I click on input it is not selected, i.e., checked.

`languages_sys` is object as:

```
{"0" : "Spain", "1": "England"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name="language"` to the input, and replace `ng-value` with `value`:

```
<input name="language" type="radio" ng-click="..." value="{{key}}" ng-model="language">
```

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35ey95f7/)**

Comment: You also had `ng-value` instead of `value`. Can you recheck in your project?

Comment: I found reason, problem was in HTML I had input inside a link